# iOS how to create scale view

Tags: ios, iphone

How to create the View that changed scale when a button is pushed.

When I push "X" of Small View, the View changed to Big View with an animation.
When I push "X" of Big View, the View changed to Small View with an animation.
And, anytime I can click "B" viewed on each view.
How to create this View?

```
 Small View
  |BBBBB|      
  |BBXBB|

  Big View
  |BBBBB|
  |BBBBB|
  |BBBBB|
  |BBBBB|
  |BBXBB|
```

Comment: if the small view is on top of the screen than it's easy, just change the y origin of the frame inside [UIView animateWithDuration] block

Comment: Though I can't hidden buttons on small view, I can do it because I changed the location of views. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        UIView *view = (UIView *)sender;
        view.frame = CGRectEqualToRect(view.frame, SMALL_RECT) ? BIG_RECT : SMALL_RECT;
    }];
}
```

Comment: you do not need any flag. You could base on the frame height :)

Comment: that's good idea, viperking. i updated my answer. cheers :)

Comment: we can even move further: `view.frame = CGRectEqualToRect(view.frame, SMALL_RECT) ? BIG_RECT : SMALL_RECT;` how awesome is this? :)

Comment: you are a genius. hahaha :-D

Comment: I like to keep things small as much as possible :) and in this case it fits nicely imho